# Bind alt + F1-F12 on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, xfce

I have keyboard without <kbd>fn</kbd> button and I want to bind <kbd>right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> to make it act as a <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> on some keyboards.

I'm using `xfce4-keyboard-settings` to bind keys.

So, the problem:
I bound <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to the command `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioMute` and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> nothing happens. **How to bind <kbd>rigth Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to `XF86AudioMute`?**

P.S: As I think, computer, instead of receiving `XF86AudioMute` after <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>, for some reason ignores `--clearmodifiers` flag, receives <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> + `XF86AudioMute` and doesn't mute audio.

Comment: If you give the `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioMute` command on a command line (not by `Alt-Gr F9`), does that mute your sound?

Comment: @ojs yes. I also tried this command with `watch` and manually press and hold alt+f9 and then audio mute doesn't toggled, but if I release alt+f9 audio mute toggles

Comment: I think your hunch about the clearmodifiers is correct, instead of using `xdotool` why not just bind the key to the correct command, something like `amixer -q set Master toggle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the keybind, then instead of using the command `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioMute` try using `amixer -q set Master toggle`. This assumes of course that you are using `amixer` as your mixer. You have to adjust your command in accordance with what you are using to adjust your volume.